# How to set TTL index for collection in MongoKit?

Tags: python, mongokit

I want to use 'Time To Live' collection feature (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) in my app (flask+mongokit).

It is possible to create TTL index for all documents in collection via MongoKit when i describe my models or i need to use pymongo instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pymongo layer to create a TTL index for all documents:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.ensure_index

Exemple assuming that you have a User mongokit model:

```
db.User.collection.ensure_index("name", 300)
```

note that TTL is now deprecated in pymongo 2.3. Use cache_for instead.

Comment: Are you sure about TTL deprecated? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/